# How to post mount flood light security lights

Tags: electrical, lighting, outdoor

I am trying to add some light for security and visibility in our backyard that serves as a parking lot. The area where I'd like to install a light fixture is in the back corner of our yard opposite of our home. This means I'll need a post of some kind to attach it to. From what I can see these types of lights are meant to attach to a junction box that is on some outside wall of a home. I can't seem to find pole mount options for this type of motion sensor activated security light:

[image]

Can anyone enlighten me on how to attach this to a pole? I was hoping to avoid installing a very wide diameter wooden pole where I could run PVC conduit along the side to an exterior grade conduit junction box attached toward the top of the pole. Namely, because that starts to look unsightly. I'm looking for something that floods the area with light but also isn't an eyesore.

Comment: Any chance you could mount it on a building wall, and higher up?

Answer (score 2):

Just about anything you do will look like an eyesore unless you're willing to spend 300 to 400 bucks on a 12 foot light pole and bury it 4'. I have seen people take a 14' 4x4 and bury it 4' and run conduit up to an exterior junction box mounted on the flat surface but those posts have a strong tendency to twist. Check with your power company. They may have an outdoor lighting program that could help you on this.  Think about installing the fixture on one of your walls.

Answer (score 1):

Make a bracket to hold a plate which then supports a junction box as necessary.

So, a hoop or u-bolt either into a support or direct into the plate as per:
[image]

Or a clamp around the pole such as:

[image]

Comment: When you say make a bracket I can't conceptualize what you're suggesting. I'd like to put this on an 8ft tall pole to keep out of people's reach.

Comment: A hopp that goes around the pile to meet the plate on either side - a classic solution. Even look at how some signs are mounted on poles.

Comment: Hi, Mike. This popped up as a "Low Quality Post"; adding your comment to the answer body would probably help. (Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use 2" RMC ac the pole and run the wires inside it,
top it with a suitable outdoor junction box and affix the lamp assembly.

https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/using-rmc-as-lighting-pole.123064/